# Using WCF Connected services proxy class slow first request

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, asp.net-core

I am porting an old project to .net core 2.0 and I had to use WCF Connected service extension to make the application able to use 2 SOAP services. However I noted that the first request made to any of the service takes too much time, after it - it works fine. I made a brand new project with only the proxy class to see if it's something wrong with the code, but the response time is exactly the same. Is it possible I am missing something or it is the way it works? Regards.